# My XBox S Controller is causing keypress events

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, xbox-one

I have An XBox One S controller connected to my Raspberry Pi over Bluetooth. All keys work except for the X (logo) and two-squares buttons. (next to hamburger button) These two buttons cause keypresses when I press them, with logo registering as key 180 and two-squares being 166. (According to xev, those are the keycodes.) Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: What driver(s) are you using for this connection?

Comment: @music2myear I was using joystick, but switched to xpadneo.

Comment: Did the problem begin before or after you switched?

Comment: @musictomyear After, but that was at the same time I started using Bluetooth instead of USB. It also occurs with Wiimotes. I'm trying the solutions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33672/joystick-acts-as-mouse-wont-stop).

Comment: @music2myear None of them worked.